# capistrano asking for password for deploy (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)

Tags: deployment, ssh, capistrano

I am logged into the remote server, made  some changes to a file,
did a git commit and push which worked fine.
Now i want to deploy and it is asking for a password when i put the one I used to logged into the remote server it rolls back...

```
Password: 
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back  
* executing "rm -rf /sites/eq-versions/20130725203900; true"
servers: ["eq-production"]
** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: eq-production (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy)
connection failed for: eq-production (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy)
```

what is wrong?

Here is the [CAPFILE](http://pastebin.com/a3x63ZeU).

Comment: Try adding `default_run_options[:pty] = true` and removing the `ssh_options` line.

Comment: @CDub thanks but It did not work. Still asking for a password :(.

Comment: Try logging in using `cap shell` and running `whoami` - is it the user you expect?

Comment: the user is what i expected but the problem is the production server (eq-production), i don't know what password to put in... tried mine, root deploy . does the username has to be same on the remote and local machine?

Comment: It shouldn't.  What's in the `~/.ssh` directory?  Are there any authorized keys?

Comment: i have my public key in the authorized key file in both servers the remote server (staging) where i ssh in to deploy and the production server which is used during the deploy to restart the servers.(note: I don't have a profile on the production server but i have one on the staging server)

Comment: So then the staging server's SSH key needs to be authorized to the production server, at least that's what it sounds like to me.  Is it?

Comment: @CDub, thanks for u'r help i had a permission pb.

Comment: No problem.  Glad you got it worked out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup [ssh login without password](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html)

Comment: can you confirm that you can ssh into the box using the user without a password? example `ssh user@doamin.com`. Once that works your cap deploy should work.

Comment: i can ssh into the remote server (staging) and call the deploy script which restart the production server.(note: I don't have a profile on the production server but i have one on the staging server)

Comment: so can you from where ever you are trying to run `cap deploy` run `ssh user@server.com` and connect without typing a password?

Comment: no, i cannot ssh into the production server i don't have a profile.

Comment: then you will need to great a profile on that server if you want to deploy to it.

Comment: I've created a profile but had the same problem but it is complaining about the deploy user(`connection failed for: eq-production (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: deploy) )` which doesn't have a password.

Comment: in my /etc/sudoer file i have `deploy ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/apache2, /etc/init.d/nginx`  which mean it should not ask for password :(

Comment: thanks for all the help the last 3 bullets points did the job. i had a permission problem...